# htaccess not working properly for sub url having more slashes

Tags: .htaccess, octobercms

I am having 2 websites. Call it **5p_front** (http://localhost/5p_front/) (Developed in **OctoberCMS**) and **5p_group** (http://localhost/5p_group/) (Developed in **CakePHP**)

In **5p_front** i have an **.htaccess** file and in which i put a condition which will redirect to **5p_group** website as soon as it finds a word having **5p_group_login** in url. Here is code below

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^5p_group_login.*$ http://localhost/5p_group [L,R=301]
```

So if someone tries to go here for example http://localhost/5p_front/5p_group_login , they will simply be redirected to here http://localhost/5p_group/ .

This works fine from home page and other subpages like about page for example http://localhost/5p_front/we-are-5p-group .

However i have one product inner page http://localhost/5p_front/product/10 and if i hover the menu item which allows me to redirect to login page, it is showing this url http://localhost/5p_front/product/5p_group_login and hence when i click on it, i am unable to redirect at http://localhost/5p_group/ as it is only recirecting to this current url only http://localhost/5p_front/product/5p_group_login which should not be the case.

Additionally, My Menu is coming dynamically and i have used [Static Pages](https://octobercms.com/index.php/plugin/rainlab-pages) plugin to create menus which **OctoberCMS** provides and i have created "Login" menu link like below.

[image]

How can i redirect the url at http://localhost/5p_group/ even if the user is at http://localhost/5p_front/product/10 and clicks on "Login" link which is showing http://localhost/5p_front/product/5p_group_login if i mouse hover on it.

Can someone guide me here what should i do in this scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule

```
RewriteRule ^5p_group_login.*$ http://localhost/5p_group [L,R=301]
```

when placed in `5p_front/.htaccess` will affect only URIs that begin with `/5p_front/5p_group_login` (because of the leading `^` in your pattern) so `/5p_front/product/5p_group_login` will not match.

If you want to rewrite URLs that have `5p_group_login` anyhwere, just use:

```
RewriteRule 5p_group_login http://localhost/5p_group [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Wow .. great explanation. Thank you.